# Fixed Topbar and Content Div

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and having some beginner troubles.

I want to have a fixed navigation bar on the top (which is fixed) so it would stick on the top even if the user scrolls the page.
and below is the content page.

how I want the page to act is that when the user scrolls the page the content page should go under the navigation bar.

in my case the the navigation bar is fixed but when scrolled the content div covers the navigation bar.

my codes are as follows

```
<div id="Container"> <!--Container Start-->
        <div id="TopBar"><!--TopBar Start-->
            <div class="fixedwidth"> <!-- Fixedwidth Start-->
                <div id="logodiv">   <!-- Logodiv Start-->
                    <img src="images/mascot.jpg"/>
                </div><!-- Logodiv End-->
                <div id="signInDiv">
                    <p><img src="images/orb.png"/>Sign In/Up</p>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- Fixedwidth End-->

        </div><!--TopBar End-->

        <div class="break"></div>

        <div id="mainContentDiv"> <!--Main Content Start-->
            <div class="fixedwidth">
                <div id="Content">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!--Main Content End-->
    </div><!--Container End-->
```

and the css code is as follows:

```
body{
        margin:0;
    }
    #TopBar{
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        color:#174269;
        position:fixed;

        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:1.2em;
        border-bottom:1px ridge black;
    }

    .fixedwidth{

        width:1050px;
        margin:0 auto;

    }

    #logodiv {
        float:left;
        padding-bottom:5px;

    }
    #logodiv img{
        width:188px;
        height:100px;

    }
    #signInDiv{
        float:right


    }
    #signInDiv img{
        position:relative;
        top:6px;

    }
    #signInDiv p{
        position:relative;
        top:20px;

    }
    .break{
        clear:both;
    }

    #mainContentDiv{

        position:relative;
        top:100px;
        width:100%;
        height:1000px;
        background-color: #0C7ECC;
    }
```

I know that it has an easy solution but just can't figure it out.

Comment: Go research the `z-index` property.

Comment: Thanks! =)) that solved my issue ^^

Answer (score 0):

The "break" element seems like something that should be removed. Look for "clearfix", which is a standard way to define a class applied to the first floating element (the TopBar). Then you can also remove the "height" on the TopBar.

One perhaps easier approach would be to set a known height for the TopBar (say 50px), and set the same value for mainContentDiv's margin-top. The text would not go underneath (as you asked), but the visual effect should be the same since your TopBar is not transparent.

Yet another possibility would be to use a "display: flexbox" on Container, and set the "flex:1" property on mainContentDiv so that it occupies the whole height except for the height needed for the TopBar. In this case, remove the hard-coded height property for the TopBar, add the clearfix class I mentioned before so that the TopBar is the same height at its elements.